# Who are "registred owners" of some domain?

Tags: pki, digital-certificate

A digital certificate issuer says that:
-  an email will be sent to "registered owners" of the domain (ex. croraf.com).

How does he know who the "registered owners" of the domain are? (and how can I tell in general who the registered owners of some domain are)

NOTE: Below that it gives the option to "send an email to admin@croraf.com, webmaster@croraf.com, hostmaster@croraf.com". So by registered owners it is meant something else (perhaps names in *whois* lookup of the domain).

Answer (score 1):

The convention is to use `hostmaster`, `postmaster` or some other "well-known" email address at a domain which is likely to be held by an entity enabled to act on behalf of that domain.

They may also pull from the whois data.  e.g. for [stackoverflow.com](https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=stackoverflow.com) it would be reasonable to allow the email to be sent to `sysadmin-team`.  The whois data is fairly indicative of someone who is responsible for the domain, because anyone who can cause the domain's whois data to change has the ability to repoint their DNS authority to another service (where they presumably have the ability to modify things), making someone who has "whois-edit" permissions capable of completely subsuming the domain.  Therefore, whoever they say is trustworthy is as good as anything else.